# Algorithm for Intersection (or Merge) of Numerical Ranges

Tags: algorithm, list, merge, range, intersection

Let's say I have a list of ranges like this:

List A) 0 to 3, 9 to 14

List B) 1 to 4, 6 to 7, 14 to 16

List C) 15 (i.e., 15 to 15)

I'd like to get a merged list of these ranges where the result would look like this:

Merged Result List) 0 to 4, 6 to 7, 9 to 16

(notice that the result is a merging/intersection/union of Lists A, B, and C)

I'm sure there's an algorithm for this, but have no idea.  Has anyone come across this before?

(pseudocode, or VB, would be great)

Adding a visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to merge rages within a single list or from all lists (and then in which order). Also, your list C) "15" - what does it mean? How can a single value specify a range?

Comment: The "15" is the whole range - it starts at 15 and ends at 15.  I guess I could have written it like: 15 to 15 (I'll update the question to reflect this).  The result is the merging, or union/intersection, of Lists A, B, and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make array/list of pairs `(Value, Flag = +1 for start or -1 for end of range)`

Sort these pairs by `Value`  (use `Flag` as secondary key in case of tie)

Make `Counter = 0`

Walk through sorted array, adding `Flag` to `Counter`

When `Counter` becomes non-zero, merged range begins.

When `Counter` becomes zero, merged range ends

P.S. If you want to merge "touching" intervals - account for `Flag` in comparator function during sorting when `Value` is the same  - for example, `(14;+1)` before `(14,-1)`

Comment: Great idea - I tried it and it was close.  Here's the result I got: 0 to 4, 6 to 7, 9 to 14, 14 to 16

Comment: Added solution for this case